# Is there anyway to capture SQL Data table using Coded UI?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I want to get the value on each cell in Data Table after running query on SQL Server, but the Test Builder can't capture the value of the cell, or the table. Is there any extension for this purpose?

Thanks, 
Lan

Answer (score 1):

I am confused as to why you want to do this, it would be very very inefficient to test database queries using Code UI. You would be much better off writing a unit test to check values returned by a query.

If for some reason you can't write unit tests or are some how testing the actual data table in SQL server. You can probable get the values from the data table by click inside a cell and then doing a search for an edit box or label and get the value from that and then use sendkeys to navigate the data table.

You can usually get the search properties for the editbox by using Windows Key + I in UITest Builder. Also note that the editbox will likely only be visible to Coded UI when it is focused (thus the click) and that the click into the grid is going to be to a particular point within the control and might be sensitive to changes in screen resolution.

Comment: +1 for the first statement. Coded-UI Tests are really not meant to worry about the data layer at all. They are meant to exercise the UI, and make sure that everything at that level is working.

Comment: I'm doing a demo test with VS SQL server application.